# Converting date string with negative time sets DateTime.Kind property different

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

Using CDate() or DateTime.TryParse(), the following two dates convert with different Kind properties.

```
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim date2 As Date

    date1 = CDate("1/29/2014 2:00 AM")
    date2 = CDate("1/29/2014 -7:00")

    Debug.WriteLine("date1: " & date1.ToString & ", date2: " & date2.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Kind {0}, {1}", date1.Kind, date2.Kind.ToString))
```

**Output**

```
date1: 1/29/2014 2:00:00 AM, date2: 1/29/2014 2:00:00 AM
Kind: Unspecified, Local
```

My system is set to Eastern Standard Time (-5 hours UTC), so that explains the 2:00 AM but why is date2 converted to local time and date1 unspecified?

Comment: Well, giving it a regular time doesn't give any hints as to whether it is local or not. Giving it a negative time makes it interpret it as a UTC offset and it converts it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"-7:00" doesn't mean what you (probably) think it does.  It of course cannot be a time since times are never negative.  But CDate() can still bake something out of it without throwing an exception, a date string can contain a signed UTC offset.  Which can be negative.

So the string can represent midnight in the UTC-7 timezone.  Since you live in UTC-5, that unambiguously turns into 2:00 AM local time.

Compare to CDate("1/29/2014 +7:00"), also midnight but on the other end of the planet.